# Unable to debug Fortran program in VS Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, fortran, gfortran, lldb

I'm trying to debug a Fortran program using Visual Studio Code (VSC) under Mac OS X Catalina (10.15.3). I can set a breakpoint and VSC breaks at that line appropriately, but I can't Watch any variables. VSC displays "error: no value" in the Watch window and when I type print <variable_name> in the terminal. I'm using the lldb debugger.

Here are the extensions I've installed

C/C++
Fortran Breakpoint Support
FORTRAN IntelliSense
Modern Fortran
Python
Jupyter
Native Debug

This is my launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "(lldb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/test",
            "args": ["${workspaceFolder}/data.txt"],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": false,
            "osx": {
                "MIMode": "lldb",
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and my tasks.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "make",
            "args": [],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
                "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

Has anyone successfully used a debugger for a Fortran program in VS Code? I can debug a C++ program with no issues.

Comment: Try going with GNU toolchain: https://www.owsiak.org/running-gdb-in-macos-sierra/ - here you can find how to build everything on macOS: https://www.owsiak.org/building-opencoarrays-on-macos-everything-from-the-sources-gcc-9-2-0/

Answer (score 1):

At present, lldb has no support for Fortran.

With some other languages (like Rust) in lieu of real support lldb is told to pretend they are C++, and that sort of works.  You could try that with lldb (you'd have to build your own copy to make the change).  But Fortran is pretty different from C++ so this would only get you so far.

gdb has Fortran support, maybe you can get VSCode to work with gdb instead?